# Migrating MPSCNNFullyConnected to MPSCNNConvolutionDataSource

Tags: ios, conv-neural-network, metal-performance-shaders

I am migrating my neural network from the deprecated:

```
init(device: MTLDevice, convolutionDescriptor: MPSCNNConvolutionDescriptor, kernelWeights: UnsafePointer<Float>, biasTerms: UnsafePointer<Float>?, flags: MPSCNNConvolutionFlags)
```

to

```
init(device: MTLDevice, weights: MPSCNNConvolutionDataSource)
```

I have implemented a `MPSCNNConvolutionDataSource` which is well debugged and which works for all of my layers except one. Just for testing purposes  I am calling here the datasource functions myself along with the deprecated init() of `MPSCNNFullyConnected` to be sure the datasource is implemented correctly. I know that this not the intended use of it, but I wanted the same data go into both MPSCNNFullyConnected() constructors. The following code runs and the NN works properly.

```
  /* This code runs as intended */
  let datasource = DataSource("test", 8, 8, 224, 1024, .reLU)
  _ = datasource.load()
    let layer = MPSCNNFullyConnected(device: device,
                                   convolutionDescriptor: datasource.descriptor(),
                                   kernelWeights: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>(mutating: datasource.weights().assumingMemoryBound(to: Float.self)),
                                   biasTerms: datasource.biasTerms(),
                                   flags: .none)
```

When I instantiate the fully connected layer with the new init() the network fails. The following code runs but the NN does not work properly.

```
  /* This code does run, but the layer does NOT output the correct values */
  let datasource = DataSource("test", 8, 8, 224, 1024, .reLU)
  let layer = MPSCNNFullyConnected(device: device, weights: datasource)
```

Any suggestions why both calls are not identical ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved it. The difference between both calls is that you have to set the layer.offset explicitly if you use:

```
init(device: MTLDevice, weights: MPSCNNConvolutionDataSource)
```

The deprecated call:

```
init(device: MTLDevice, convolutionDescriptor: MPSCNNConvolutionDescriptor, kernelWeights: UnsafePointer<Float>, biasTerms: UnsafePointer<Float>?, flags: MPSCNNConvolutionFlags)
```

seems to have done that implicitly.

This code works:

```
let datasource = DataSource("test", 8, 8, 224, 1024, .reLU)
let layer = MPSCNNFullyConnected(device: device, weights: datasource)
layer.offset = MPSOffset(x: 8/2, y: 8/2, z: 0)
```

I guess this documented nowhere ! Thanks Apple for three days hardcore debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple docs for most of this Metal stuff seems to have disappeared but it's still there if you look in the header files (or Alt-click in Xcode and then jump to the definition).

The ordering of the weights hasn't changed. You still load them the same way as before.

For an example of how to write such a data source object, check out this repo: https://github.com/hollance/YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph/blob/2ba3435bfacb8d2f792b95887fc9df85d7048ae1/TinyYOLO-NNGraph/TinyYOLO-NNGraph/YOLO.swift#L254